# Deploy error about Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, deployment, heroku

I have created a new app on Heroku on Windows XP, accessed the created URL, it displayed the welcome page, then I deployed Rails app data to Heroku, then accessed the same URL again, but I found it displayed an error page with an "application error". I have no idea, the Rails app is open source, I downloaded it from the internet, I have done nothing to it except overwriting the document's name.

Comment: is git installed, this could cause this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run `heroku logs` to see what the problem is.

Comment: D:\myapp\foruda>heroku logs
C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/heroku-1.18.2/lib/heroku/commands/base.rb:4
:in ``': No such file or directory - git config heroku.remote (Errno::ENOENT)
from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/heroku-1.18.2/lib/heroku/comma
ds/base.rb:46:in `extract_app_from_git_config'
from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/heroku-1.18.2/lib/heroku/comma   
ds/base.rb:37:in `extract_app_in_dir'
from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/heroku-1.18.2/lib/heroku/comma
ds/base.rb:25:in `extract_app'        this's one part of the logs,i don't understand

Answer (score 1):

did it have a database required? perhaps you need to run `heroku rake db:migrate`

Comment: i have try it,but it still occured the error which i have shown on the first floor

Answer (score 0):

Try running "heroku stack" and find out what stack you are current on. I spend 5 hours before finding out that i need to create a stack on cedar to make my app works. Basically you need to run "Heroku create --stack cedar" during your first heroku create command.

Best of luck.